# how to place a decimal point just before last two digit of a number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query as below

```
Select sum(total) from sales
```

it will give the result as `123456789` because in back end data is stored with out decimal point.
I need to format it as `1234567.89`

i tried

```
select CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(total)) from sales
```

but it give the output as `123456789.00`

> how to make it as 1234567.89

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide by 100.0:

```
select CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), SUM(total) / 100.0)
from sales
```

Comment: Thanks..upvoted the same..will mark it as answer after 10 min :)

Answer (score 1):

You should simply divide by 100. Something like this:

```
select sum(total) / 100 from sales
```

Comment: thanks..but your logic will avoid the last two digit. eg: if it is `4900` it will give the result as `49` not `49.00`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(total) / 100 from sales;
```

Comment: thanks..but your logic will avoid the last two digit. eg: if it is `4900` it will give the result as `49` not `49.00`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert it to a decimal on the back end.

```
create table decimalnumbers(
deci_number decimal(10,2));
```

Comment: i cannot do it..its a customized s/w table..i need to convert it at front end